# Remoting from a WORKGROUP PC to Domain-Joined PC

Tags: windows, powershell, remote

I was wondering if it was possible to remote from a WORKGROUP PC to a domain-joined PC, using only the local credentials of the domain-joined PC. I know this is definitely doable through PSExec, thought in this situation the domain-joined PC has the local administrative shares disabled, and as such PSExec is not a usable solution. In this sort of situation, is remoting from a WORKGROUP PC to another PC using the local credentials of the other PC a possible thing?

I have attempted sending remote commands through Invoke-WMIMethod, and have added the client PC to the TrustedHosts list, to no avail. I'm able to connect to the domain controller using a domain administrator account, though I want to be able to connect to a domain-joined account using the local details for the remote PC. I have also tried Invoke-Command through PowerShell, also to no avail, and Enter-PSSession.

Having remote administrative shares disabled unfortunately complicates matters, though it is company policy (don't ask me why, no clue). I can netsh the machine remotely so I don't believe it's anything to do with the network configuration, so I'm just looking for any sort of solution or workaround that will allow me to remote to a domain-joined PC using that a local user account on that PC remotely from a WORKGROUP PC. I don't necessarily want an interactive session such that PSExec can create, simply to execute commands remotely.

Comment: Please clarify what credentials you want to use to access the domain joined PC?  Sounds like you do NOT want to use domain, but credentials local to the domain joined PC.  If so, be sure to use the computer name as the domain when you enter the username.  So "computer1\administrator" and the associated password.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you specify full credentials (domain, user, and password) when you connect, otherwise, the default is usually to use the current user's credentials.  Your current domain will probably be the computer and the local account you are using there.

For PSSessions, first the remote machine has to have remote sessions enabled.  Then you have to create a new session and connect it to the remote machine before you can enter it.  [Here](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-remote-management,2-781.html) is a basic tutorial that may help you understand the details of PS sessions.  However, it does not address entering a domain computer from a non-domain one.